# How to set padding for UILabel using @IBDesignable property?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, ibdesignable

This is how looks my subclass for `UILabel`:

```
@IBDesignable class AttributedLabel: UILabel {

    @IBInspectable var padding: CGFloat = 0

    override func drawTextInRect(rect: CGRect) {
        super.drawTextInRect(UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, UIEdgeInsetsMake(padding, padding, padding, padding)))
    } 
}
```

I correctly set `padding` in storyboard but It doesnt work because padding is still `0`.

**What to do to make it working? Is it possible to render it live in Storyboard?**

Answer (score 1):

Use like this; Change top , bottom, left, right inset paddings.

```
@IBDesignable class AttributedLabel: UILabel {

    @IBInspectable var topInset: CGFloat = 5.0
    @IBInspectable var bottomInset: CGFloat = 5.0
    @IBInspectable var leftInset: CGFloat = 7.0
    @IBInspectable var rightInset: CGFloat = 7.0

    override func drawTextInRect(rect: CGRect) {
        let insets = UIEdgeInsets(top: topInset, left: leftInset, bottom: bottomInset, right: rightInset)
        super.drawTextInRect(UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, insets))
    }

    override func intrinsicContentSize() -> CGSize {
        var intrinsicSuperViewContentSize = super.intrinsicContentSize()
        intrinsicSuperViewContentSize.height += topInset + bottomInset
        intrinsicSuperViewContentSize.width += leftInset + rightInset
        return intrinsicSuperViewContentSize
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your subclass looks incomplete. As mentioned in the documentation, you should override both of these methods :

```
public func textRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect, limitedToNumberOfLines numberOfLines: Int) -> CGRect
public func drawTextInRect(rect: CGRect)
```

Here is an example implementation that should work :

```
@IBDesignable class AttributedLabel : UILabel
{
    @IBInspectable var padding: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            self.textInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: self.padding, left: self.padding, bottom: self.padding, right: self.padding)
        }
    }
    var textInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero {
        didSet {
            self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
        }
    }

    override func textRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect, limitedToNumberOfLines numberOfLines: Int) -> CGRect
    {
        var insets = self.textInsets
        let insetRect = UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(bounds, insets)
        let textRect = super.textRectForBounds(insetRect, limitedToNumberOfLines: numberOfLines)
        insets = UIEdgeInsets(top: -insets.top, left: -insets.left, bottom: -insets.bottom, right: -insets.right)
        return UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(textRect, insets)
    }

    override func drawTextInRect(rect: CGRect) {
        super.drawTextInRect(UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, self.textInsets))
    }
}
```

You will not be able to render it live in Interface Builder though.

Comment: Why can you not render it live in Interface builder?